# How to generate test report in XML

Tags: go, reportportal, go-testing

I have tests (Unit and Integration) in Go and I need to generate a report in XML (Preferably Junit).
Also each test tests a certain functionality. Hence I would like them to be grouped/tagged in report.

The only thing I could find in internet was [Go Junit Report](https://github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report).
This tool converts test run output to junit XML. I need a way to tag features in Go test and be included in the report.

How can I add tags in Go and get it in output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [GoTestSum](https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum)

Also, since ReportPortal is tagged in the question, i would suggest that you try [GoRP](https://github.com/avarabyeu/goRP) client and try to implement the integration with your testing framework by yourself. Reporting API is quite well described [here](https://reportportal.io/docs/Log-Data-in)